# Laravel - Eager load a non-relationship method (N+1 issue)

Tags: php, multithreading, laravel, laravel-5

With laravel's eager loading, I can do something like

`$forums = Forum::with('posts', 'threads')->get();`

To  get the threads as its posts and forum without doing many queries.

However, I have a method that gets the last post of the forum.

This is my method in `Forum.php`

```
public function lastThread()
{
    $forums = $this->arrayOfIDs(); // get array of all ids, even subforum's subforums.
    return Thread::whereIn('forum_id', $forums)->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->first();
}
```

This is my partial view to get the last thread:

```
@if ($subforum->lastThread())

    <a href="{{ viewThread($subforum->lastThread()) }}">
        {{ $subforum->lastThread()->title }}
    </a>
    <br>
    <a href="{{ viewPost($subforum->lastThread()->lastPost) }}"> {{ trans('forum/post.last_post') }}
        :</a>
    <a href="{{ viewProfile($subforum->lastThread()->lastPost->user) }}"> {{ $subforum->lastThread()->lastPost->user->info() }}</a>
    <br>
    {{ $subforum->lastThread()->lastPost->created_at }}

@endif
```

As you can see, if I am doing `$subforum->lastThread()` a lot. I can store it in a variable like `$lastThread = $subforum->lastThread()` and then do something like `$lastThread->created_at` to reduce the number of queries but I figured it would be much easier if just include it with the original query to get all forums.

Something like:`$forums = Forum::with('posts', 'threads', 'lastThread')->get();` perhaps? I have tried doing a `hasOne` relation for this method but that does not work because the last thread does not necessarily belong to that specific subforum.

Anyway, how can I best fix this N+1 problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Is that last thread already included in your $forums collection (as a relationship of course)?

Answer (score 0):

you have endless options,

if the Cache class is right for you than I will go with this path, you can also do this:

```
protectd $lastThread;

public function lastThread()
{
     if ($this->lastThread) return $this->lastThread;
     return $this->fetchLastThread();
}

    public function fetchLastThread() {
         $forums = $this->arrayOfIDs(); // get array of all ids, even subforum's subforums.
         $this->lastThread = Thread::whereIn('forum_id', $forums)->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->first();
         return  $this->lastThread;
}
```